# Accessing (getting) the test result in PyTest (PASSED100%)

Tags: python, pytest

I coded a test function using Pytest framework. The result of the function execution is successfully passed. In the terminal window Paytest displays a report - 100% [PASSED].

How can I access the result of an executed test and, for example, store it in a variable, or create a condition

`if <my_test_yield_function> == 'PASSED   [100%]:'` ?

I need this information to generate a Test execution report (PDF file form) using the Pytest fixture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp4yh.png)

I decided to correct my question more clearly using an example of the code that I want to implement:

```
import pytest
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def pdf_test_report_maker(request):
    yield
    pdf_report = canvas.Canvas("test_report.pdf")
    pdf_report.drawString(40, 700, f"Test name: {request.function.__name__}")
    **if  <my_test_yield_function> == "PASSED   [100%]":** # here is the problem
        pdf_report.drawString(60, 645, "PASSED   [100%]")
    else:
        pdf_report.drawString(60, 645, "FAILED   [100%]")
    pdf_report.save()
```